# where to put gem script files for compass (css_splitter)

Tags: rubygems

first time working with gem/ruby files. need a bit of help here.

Basically we have asp.net application that uses SASS + COMPASS.

To address css file size limitation, we wanted to use css_splitter script (css_splitter.rake and css_splitter.rb): https://gist.github.com/1131536

Basically, after compass compiles, splitter should kick in and split the generated css file into 2 or more.

What I have tired:

1. The sass config file is under: D:\myapp\mainsite\sass\config.rb
2. I put css_splitter.rake and css_splitter.rb into the folder above.
3. modified config.rb to reference to "css_splitter.rb" as follow:

> ```
> require 'susy'
> require 'css_splitter'
>
> http_path = "/"
> css_dir = "../stylesheets"
> sass_dir = ""
> images_dir = "../img"
> javascripts_dir = "../Scripts"
> sass_options = {:full_exception => true }
> output_style = :compressed
> line_comments = false
>
> on_stylesheet_saved do |path|
>   CssSplitter.split(path) unless path[/\d+$/]
> end
> ```

1. When i compiled project, the error I got was: LoadError on line 36 of D: no such file to load -- css_splitter
2. I also notice there is a D:\myapp\sass\ruby\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.8 folder, I put css_splitter.rake and css_splitter.rb into that folder too, but good the same error.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother with rake.
The easiest way to do this is to copy and paste the entire Module CssSplitter into your config.rb file, and change Module to class.

Then at the bottom, add the on_stylesheet_saved method override.
something like this:
https://gist.github.com/3559165

This may not be the ideal configuration, but it works. It should give you Screen, Screen_2, Screen_3 ...etc in your stylesheets dir.
Let me know if you make any progress!

Comment: your suggestion worked for me, but I did notice that the original css file remains unchanged. My styles split into three style sheets. The original, plus two more. However the original is not trimmed to exclude what was split out into the 2nd and 3rd style sheet. Were you (or anyone else) aware of this?

Comment: Hey Ben, I believe this is intended. You need to add a conditional so that the other two files only load if IE9 and below. That way you can still have one stylesheet for all other browsers. For example: `<!--[if lte IE 9]><link href="/stylesheets/app_2.css" /><![endif]-->`