# How to install compass code to split style sheets for IE selector limit

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, compass-sass

IE 8 and lower has a limit to the number of selectors allowed in a single style sheet and once the limit is reached the style sheet needs to be split. Apparently someone addressed this in Compass by creating a way to have Compass do this automatically, and created a gist about it. I however don't have the skills to know what the next step is and there is little in the way of documentation on what to do with this code. Can anyone help with how to integrate this into my Compass install?

Ref: https://gist.github.com/1131536

Thanks much!

Comment: I found that this technique has worked for me!
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066206/where-to-put-gem-script-files-for-compass-css-splitter/12222613#12222613][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066206/where-to-put-gem-script-files-for-compass-css-splitter/12222613#12222613

Comment: thanks Mack I will give this a try and report back

Comment: Thanks @Mack your solution worked for me and putted me on track. I've finally preferred to use the require solution which looks cleaner to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create **css_spliter.rb** file (as described **[in your Ref](https://gist.github.com/ChristianPeters/1131536)**) beside your ***config.rb*** file, at the root of your sass project.

Add the following line at the beginning of your ***config.rb*** file

```
require 'css_splitter'
```

And add the 3 following lines at the end (of ***config.rb***)

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |path|
  CssSplitter.split(path) unless path[/\d+$/]
end
```

Then run `compass compile` as you usually do. You won't see the files ***myFile_2.css***, ***myFile_3.css***, ... appear in the logs but they are well created in your css folder. Also the command `compass clean` won't remove them, you'll have to dele them manually from your ***css/*** folder.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, there is a Node.js app called [Bless](http://blesscss.com/) that will provide you this functionality. It can run server side or on your local machine.

If you happen to be using [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) to compile your Sass/Compass files, it's baked in, you just have to enable it in project settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the css_splitter solution forgets to remove the code from the first file. Now I have 2 files, the first one is all of my css and the second generated file has the 2nd half of the original file. So I have 150% the amount of CSS as I used to... I did fix my problem in IE though :)

Comment: With the css_splitter, you only load the second file for IE9 and below, so for all other browsers you can still have one single stylesheet. For example: `<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/app_2.css")"><![endif]-->`